# How to launch a web page after installation with Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, vsinstaller

I would like to launch an URL after the installer finishes. I added an *.url file to the project content and added the content files in the Visual Studio Installer project. Then I try to add the *.url in the Commit Custom Action putting the name of the file in the Name field, the EntryPoint says "Commit" and the InstallerClass in false.

When I compile the Visual Studio Installer project it game me an error that Entry point 'Commit' not found in module for custom action *.url

Is it possible to do this without adding an InstallerClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a VB script file to run a shell command on the URL file. Look [here](http://openlandscape.net/2009/03/23/executing-shell-commands-from-a-visual-studio-deployment-project/)

Comment: The issue is that the page is launched before the installer dialog is closed.

Comment: VS setup does not allow a very fin control over the custom action scheduling. You must open the MSI file in ORCA and increase the custom action sequence.